# Azure Function - Blob trigger, how to rename blob that triggered function?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am new to blob triggers in Azure Function apps and need a bit of help.
I am struggling to find resources on how to rename the blob that triggered the function.

I have a function app that is triggered when a new blob is uploaded to a container, the file is processed and I need a way on how to 'mark' it as processed, therefore I want to rename the blob.

This is my function:

```
[FunctionName("ProcessFile")]
public async Task Run([BlobTrigger("storage-test-container/{name}", Connection = "BlobConnection")] Stream myBlob
    , [Blob("storage-test-container/{name}", FileAccess.Write)] Stream outboundBlob, string name, ILogger log)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(myBlob))
    {
        var textAsString = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

        // Process text then rename file ...
    }

}
```

How would I go about renaming the file? Is it even possible in this scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How would I go about renaming the file?

Considering renaming a blob is not natively supported, what you will need to do is copy the source blob with a different name and then delete it. That is equivalent of renaming a blob.

> Is it even possible in this scenario?

Even though it is technically possible to do so, I would not recommend it. When you copy the blob, a new blob will be created and that would fire your Function again. Thus you would end up in an infinite loop.

A better approach would be to create a separate blob container (e.g. `storage-test-container-processed`) and then copy the source blob to this container and delete it once the blob is copied successfully. Essentially you will be moving a blob instead of renaming it.

Comment: Thanks, this cleared up a few of my concerns. I'm guessing I would have to make use of a container/blob client to implement your suggestion?

Comment: `I'm guessing I would have to make use of a container/blob client to implement your suggestion?` - That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

you can use {name} from the trigger path.

```
Console.WriteLine("This is the filename: " + name);
```